# Summation of Cosine Series

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Find the summation of the series $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{\sin }^2}\left( {\frac{{k + 1}}{{n + 2}}\pi } \right)} $

My approach is as follow

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{{\sin }^2}\left( {\frac{{k + 1}}{{n + 2}}\pi } \right)}  \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( {1 - \cos \left( {\frac{{2k + 2}}{{n + 2}}\pi } \right)} \right)} $

$ \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\left( 1 \right)}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\cos \left( {\frac{{2k + 2}}{{n + 2}}\pi } \right)}  \Rightarrow \left( {n + 1} \right) - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\cos \left( {\frac{{2k + 2}}{{n + 2}}\pi } \right)} $

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\cos \left( {\frac{{2k + 2}}{{n + 2}}\pi } \right)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{{n + 2}} + \frac{2}{{n + 2}}k} \right)} ;a = \frac{{2\pi }}{{n + 2}};d = \frac{2}{{n + 2}}$

From the website I got the following formula but the summation of the series is from **$0$ to $n-1$**.

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\cos \left( {a + kd} \right)}  = \frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{{nd}}{2}} \right)}}{{\sin \left( {\frac{d}{2}} \right)}} \times \cos \left( {a + \frac{{\left( {n - 1} \right)d}}{2}} \right)$

Where as in the question it is from **$0$ to $n$**, a total of $n+1$ terms. How do I proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{\sin\frac{(n+1)d}{2}}{\sin \frac{d}{2}} \cdot \cos(a + \dfrac{nd}{2})$

For summation from $0$ to $n$
That will  work

A very basic proof if you want would be substitute n = t -1 and then using the summation formula for cosine.

[Proof of summation formula of cosine and sine up to n-1 terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro)

Answer (score 0):

Move the last term of the sum out of the sum.  The remaining sum will match your reference.
$$\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k) \right) + f(n)  \text{.}$$